# android threading - locking UI?

Tags: android, multithreading, progress

In my application I have a screen where the user can login. The login details are sent to the web and some data is downloaded into a spinner. I implemented a progress dialog to the application so that the app wouldn't lock up when the app is accessing the web and downloading. The progress dialog seems to work fine but when the task is finished it doesn't seem to update my spinner - I actually have to click the spinner to show the data that has been downloaded. The notifyDataSetChanged() method doesn't seem to work, which would usually display the first item by default if I didn't have any threading. Here is some code.

The code which starts the progressdialog

```
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging in...", "Please wait", true, false);        Thread thread = new
 Thread(this); thread.start();
```

The run method - in here the spinner dataset is changed

```
public void run() {
    myMethodThatDoesStuff();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

and the handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Finally, the bit in myMethodThatDoesStuff that changes spinner dataset

```
aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        //ADDING SOME DATA HERE
//DATA ADDED
                        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spin.setAdapter(aa);
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: without threading this works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use AsyncTask.

```
private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  protected onPreExecute() {
   pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging in...", "Please wait", true, false);     
  }

 protected Long doInBackground(Void... void) {
     doCalculation() ;
     ....    
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     .....
     pd.dismiss();
     aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

}

Comment: The exact same thing is happening when I use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `pd.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to hide the spinner, inside the handler code